# Featured Video Plus Not Display on Facebook Instant Article (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using Featured Video Plus plugin to replace featured images with video (the_post_thumbnail). But the video is not display on Facebook Instant Articles. It just detect and display featured image, not video.

Anyone have solution for this? Thanks!

Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-video-plus/

Code detect:

```
<figure>
<img src="img-url-here.jpg"/>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ..

```
<?php $post_id = get_the_ID();?>

<figure>
<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_video_url( $post_id );?>"/>
</figure>
```

Comment: Try this <?php echo get_the_post_video_url( $post_id ) ;?>